# xcode iOS 9 Keyboard Issue: -endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated called without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard, ios9

My old project is having an issue with the iOS 9 Keyboard. After the library that I developed was installed through Cocoapods, I am getting this error on the simulator when trying to use the Keyboard.

```
-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x78f0ff60; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x78f10240>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

Keyboard behavior:

- Letters with 'accents' (example: â) are popping up even without holding the character
- The dismiss keyboard button does not dismiss the Keyboard. It will only display the options 'Split' and 'Dock'

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling Xcode, because maybe the application became corrupt somehow, and if that doesn't work, also try deleting its library files (~/library/application support/xcode    and        ~/library/containers/xcode) because they might also be corrupt. Hope this helps!